# Display post from child category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
    <div id="content">
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'hide_empty'=> 0,
        'child_of' => 10, //Child From Boxes Category 
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        echo '<div class="one_fourth">';
        echo '<h1 class="valignmiddle uppercase title-bold">'.$cat->name.'<img src="'.$cat->term_icon.'" alt=""  class="alignleft"/>'.'<br />'.'<span class="solutions">'.$cat->description.'</span>'.'</h1>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<span>';
        //How do I get these child post titles here 
        echo '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <hr />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #content -->
```

I'm using it to get categories from parent Boxes category and display Name and Icon from child categories. How to display posts titles from child categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so within your foreach loop you can do a separate query to get all the posts by current category ID

```
$args= array("category" => $cat->cat_ID);
$posts_in_category = get_posts($args);
```

and then loop through these results to output each post's title by accessing the title member variable

```
foreach($posts_in_category as $current_post) {
    echo $current_post->title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I have another doubt. How I set links to each post title?

Comment: Thanks again for help to resolve my doubt. This is the code fro create a link for each title. 
<li><a href="<?=$current_post->guid;?>"><?=$current_post->post_title;?></a></li>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for that passing `$cat->term_id` as the category to query. I'd create a function in `functions.php`:

```
function the_posts_titles_so_18682717( $cat_id )
{
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'category'         => $cat_id,
        'orderby'          => 'post_date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    );
    $the_posts = get_posts( $args );
    if( $the_posts )
    {
        foreach( $the_posts as $post )
        {
            printf(
                '<h4><a href="%s">%s</a>',
                get_permalink( $post->ID ),
                $post->post_title
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And call it in the point of the template you need the child titles:

```
echo '<span>';
//How do I get these child post titles here 
the_posts_titles_so_18682717( $cat->term_id );
echo '</span>';
```